# Link two separate 3D rings in 4D without breaking or cutting

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Is it possible to link two rings (toruses) without breaking or cutting either of them, if you have access to 4 dimensions?

On page 11 of *Geometry, Relativity and the Fourth Dimension* (1977), Rudolf Rucker describes a Prof. Zollner who wanted to prove the existence of 4D beings (spirits) by asking them to link two rings carved out of two different kinds of wood, without breaking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topological constraints that exist in a space do not necessarily exist in a higher space -- linking rings should be possible by the following steps:

- move one ring entirely into a reference 3D space and move the other ring out of this space
- move one section of this other ring inside the circle of the reference ring, and within the reference 3D space: at this point only a small part of the ring is in the reference 3D space
- move the rest of the ring into the reference 3D space in a way that the ring links with the reference ring.